# libGDX: How to let the camera point to moving sprite?

Tags: scroll, libgdx, orthographic

I'm new to libGDX and android game dev. And I want to achieve this: 
I have a `Screen` and within it, a ball sprite that is moving along the X axis. Now I want to center the viewport to the sprite when it moves. Just like in Angry birds, where the camera follows the bird flying across the sky.

How can I implement that within my game using `OrthographicCamera`?

Answer (score 12):

This took me a while of Googling and testing, but I just found something and I think others may appreciate it.

To move the camera (and if you are using a spriteBatch), make sure to call setProjectionMatrix.

Ex:

```
camera.position.y += 5;  // or whatever you want to change y by...
camera.position.x += 5;
camera.update();    
spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
```

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 3):

In case you haven't figured this out yet, you need to convert the ball position to the camera position using

```
camera.unproject(ballPosition)
```

This converts the screen coordinates into world coordinates. Then call

```
camera.position(ballPosition)
```

to set the camera position to your ball's location in the world.

Answer (score 2):

The

```
camera.translate(...);
```

function translates all of the involved attributes the camera by the given data. After the operation you need to call

```
camera.update();
```

to calculate the new matrices of the camera. This will push the camera to the direction you want.